# How to align by height all images inside a card deck?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Need to align all height images inside a card-deck on bootstrap 4 without adjusting it via height since the responsive works fine alredy.

I attached a snippet where you can see my problem, cards are all same height but not the image, I know this question was asked before but couldn't find a good solution for that.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row mb-5">
    <div class="col-12">  
  <div class="card-deck">
   <div class="card">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503066211613-c17ebc9daef0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
    <div class="card-body">
     <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
     <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
     <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="card">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ2QWzz0XPxgLu05I1BlN_eOMcxrOfFiQxAoGA_ICSouwnLOVbP" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
    <div class="card-body">
     <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
     <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
     <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="card">
    <img src="https://assets.afcdn.com/story/20180709/1258610_w767h767c1cx304cy194.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
    <div class="card-body">
     <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
     <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
     <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="card">
    <img src="https://www.aspinallfoundation.org/media/4231/img_2071.jpg?center=0.40740740740740738,0.57608695652173914&mode=crop&quality=75&width=768&height=412&rnd=132022209070000000" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
    <div class="card-body">
     <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
     <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
     <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 4th image not loaded.. image path is wrong.. Image not in the file

Comment: Do u want all images are same height?

Comment: @Manikandan2811 images are from google you can get whatever u want, and yes I wan't to get all the images same height but without using height:100px or height:10vw etc, because I want the repsonsive that provides bootstrap alredy

Comment: You need to set the height of the image in the card.

Comment: ok.. can i provide the alternate code without using height with responsive?

Comment: you need all image same `height` & `width`

Comment: Which image height is you want?

Comment: @LaljiTadhani that's the problem, images can be any height or width

Comment: There is NO CSS method of equalising heights of elements that do not share a parent. You will need Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should put all images inside a `div` tag. Then just assign same height to that one.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <title></title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row mb-5">
        <div class="col-12">  
      <div class="card-deck">
       <div class="card">
        <div class="my-auto" style="height: 100%">
                       <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503066211613-c17ebc9daef0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                    </div>
        <div class="card-body">
         <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
         <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
         <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="card">
        <div class="my-auto" style="height: 100%">
            <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ2QWzz0XPxgLu05I1BlN_eOMcxrOfFiQxAoGA_ICSouwnLOVbP" class="card-img-top" alt="..."></div>
        <div class="card-body">
         <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
         <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
         <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="card">
        <div class="my-auto" style="height: 100%">
            <img src="https://assets.afcdn.com/story/20180709/1258610_w767h767c1cx304cy194.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            </div>
        <div class="card-body">
         <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
         <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
         <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="card">
        <div class="my-auto" style="height: 100%">
            <img src="https://www.aspinallfoundation.org/media/4231/img_2071.jpg?center=0.40740740740740738,0.57608695652173914&mode=crop&quality=75&width=768&height=412&rnd=132022209070000000" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            </div>
        <div class="card-body">
         <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
         <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
         <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
        </div>
         </div>
        </div>
        </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And it's better to design all the images in same height. It may solve your problem

Comment: in the snippet u provided images are not the same height

Comment: It's because those images are several sizes. If you need images like that then it's better to make the `div` as same height and let the image be inside there

Answer (score 1):

If you need to align images in the same height, then all images should be the same width and height. 'or' we can also align those my below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.card-deck .card').each(function(){
  var img_src = $(this).find(".card-img img").attr("src");
  $(this).find(".card-img").attr('style','background-image:url('+img_src+');');
  });
});
```

```css
.card-deck .card .card-img {
 background-size:cover;
 background-position:top center;
 height:120px;
}
.card-deck .card .card-img img{
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row mb-5">
    <div class="col-12">  
  <div class="card-deck">
   <div class="card">
      <div class="card-img">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503066211613-c17ebc9daef0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        </div>
    <div class="card-body">
     <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
     <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
     <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="card">
      <div class="card-img">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ2QWzz0XPxgLu05I1BlN_eOMcxrOfFiQxAoGA_ICSouwnLOVbP" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        </div>
    <div class="card-body">
     <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
     <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
     <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="card">
      <div class="card-img">
    <img src="https://assets.afcdn.com/story/20180709/1258610_w767h767c1cx304cy194.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        </div>
    <div class="card-body">
     <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
     <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
     <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="card">
      <div class="card-img">
    <img src="https://www.aspinallfoundation.org/media/4231/img_2071.jpg?center=0.40740740740740738,0.57608695652173914&mode=crop&quality=75&width=768&height=412&rnd=132022209070000000" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        </div>
    <div class="card-body">
     <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
     <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
     <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

As i mentioned its done by giving that image as background images..shown in above example 
Please check with above code.... let me know if you need any changes

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row mb-5">
    <div class="col-12">  
        <div class="card-deck">
            <div class="card">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503066211613-c17ebc9daef0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                    <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ2QWzz0XPxgLu05I1BlN_eOMcxrOfFiQxAoGA_ICSouwnLOVbP" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                    <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <img src="https://assets.afcdn.com/story/20180709/1258610_w767h767c1cx304cy194.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                    <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <img src="https://www.aspinallfoundation.org/media/4231/img_2071.jpg?center=0.40740740740740738,0.57608695652173914&mode=crop&quality=75&width=768&height=412&rnd=132022209070000000" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                    <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
<script>

    //If using jquery
        var imageWidth = $('.card-img-top').width();
        $('.card-img-top').css('height', imageWidth + 'px');


    //If using javascript
        var imageWidth = document.getElementsByClassName('card-img-top');
        for(var i=0; i<imageWidth.length;i++){
            imageWidth[i].style.height = imageWidth[i].width + "px";
        }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Not a good solution since u lost all the aspect ratio and also if you resize it in some views height destroy the image

Comment: Hey, Cristian try this solution, it would work on all devices.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row mb-5">
    <div class="col-12">
    <div class="card-deck">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="image" style="background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503066211613-c17ebc9daef0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60);"></div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
          <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="image" style="background-image: url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ2QWzz0XPxgLu05I1BlN_eOMcxrOfFiQxAoGA_ICSouwnLOVbP);"></div>
        <img src="" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
          <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="image" style="background-image: url(https://assets.afcdn.com/story/20180709/1258610_w767h767c1cx304cy194.jpg);"></div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
          <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="image" style="background-image: url(https://www.aspinallfoundation.org/media/4231/img_2071.jpg?center=0.40740740740740738,0.57608695652173914&mode=crop&quality=75&width=768&height=412&rnd=132022209070000000);"></div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
          <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

**css**

```
.card .image {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    padding-bottom: 66.6%;
    background-position: center;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need aspect ratio for image, you can use this code in your css:

`.card-img-top: {height:250px}`

Answer (score 0):

try this with height!

```css
.card-img{
  overflow:hidden;
  display:flex;
    height:200px;
  justify-content:center
}
.card-img img{
height:100%;
  width:auto
}

@media(max-width:568px){
.card-img{
height:auto
}
.card-img img{
height:auto !important;
width:100%;
}
}
```

```html
<head>
<title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row mb-5">
    <div class="col-12">  
  <div class="card-deck">
   <div class="card">
    <div class="card-img">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503066211613-c17ebc9daef0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        </div>
    <div class="card-body">
     <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
     <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
     <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="card">
        <div class="card-img">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ2QWzz0XPxgLu05I1BlN_eOMcxrOfFiQxAoGA_ICSouwnLOVbP" class="card-img-top" alt="..."></div>
    <div class="card-body">
     <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
     <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
     <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="card">
    <div class="card-img"><img src="https://assets.afcdn.com/story/20180709/1258610_w767h767c1cx304cy194.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="..."></div>
    <div class="card-body">
     <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
     <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
     <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="card">
    <div class="card-img"><img src="https://www.aspinallfoundation.org/media/4231/img_2071.jpg?center=0.40740740740740738,0.57608695652173914&mode=crop&quality=75&width=768&height=412&rnd=132022209070000000" class="card-img-top" alt="..."></div>
    <div class="card-body">
     <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
     <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
     <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope the code below helps. I added a figure tag with a `thumb_container` class to wrap the `img` tags.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>

figure.thumb_container{
    margin: 0 0 1rem;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background: transparent;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 100%;
}
img {
border-top-left-radius: calc(.25rem - 1px);
    border-top-right-radius: calc(.25rem - 1px);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

</style>
</head>



<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row mb-5">
   <div class="col-12">
    <div class="card-deck">
     <div class="card">
      <figure class="thumb_container">
       <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503066211613-c17ebc9daef0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=500&amp;q=60" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
      </figure>
      <div class="card-body">
       <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
       <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
       <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="card">
      <figure class="thumb_container">
       <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ2QWzz0XPxgLu05I1BlN_eOMcxrOfFiQxAoGA_ICSouwnLOVbP" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
      </figure>
      <div class="card-body">
       <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
       <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
       <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="card">
      <figure class="thumb_container">
       <img src="https://assets.afcdn.com/story/20180709/1258610_w767h767c1cx304cy194.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
      </figure>
      <div class="card-body">
       <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
       <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
       <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="card">
      <figure class="thumb_container">
       <img src="https://www.aspinallfoundation.org/media/4231/img_2071.jpg?center=0.40740740740740738,0.57608695652173914&amp;mode=crop&amp;quality=75&amp;width=768&amp;height=412&amp;rnd=132022209070000000" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
      </figure>
      <div class="card-body">
       <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
       <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
       <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```